# Best way to exclude records from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I got the following tables (just an example): vehicles, vehicle_descriptions, vehicle_parts

vehicles have 1 to many with vehicle_descriptions and vehicle_parts. There may not be a corresponding vehicle_description/part for a given vehicle.

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles
   LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles d ON vehicles.vin = d.vin AND d.summary NOT LIKE 'honda'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN        
   (SELECT SUM(desc_total) FROM vehicle_descriptions WHERE NOT LIKE desc 'honda' GROUP BY vin) b 
   ON vehicles.vin = vehicle_b.vin
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT SUM(part_count) FROM vehicle_parts WHERE part_for NOT LIKE 'honda' GROUP BY vin) c ON vehicles.vin = c.vin
```

If either vehicle_desc, vehicles, or part contains the exclusion term, the whole record should not show up in the result set. The query above will return a record even if one of the tables contain the exclusion term Honda. How would I fix the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using any of the information in either sum() as part of what you show, just to decide whether to include the vehicle. And you're doing an unnecessary self join in your first clause. Generally in situations like this, the "exists" and "not exists" clauses work well. So what about this? I'll use Oracle syntax, you can convert to ANSI of course.

```
    SELECT * FROM vehicles v where summary <> 'honda' 
and not exists (select 1 from vehicle_descriptions d where d.vin = v.vin and d.desc <> 'honda') 
and not exists (select 1 from vehicle_parts p where p.vin = v.vin and p.part_for <> 'honda')
```

Comment: +1 (+3 if I could!) for mentioning the non-use of `SUM()` data, the unneeded self join, and `EXISTS`. Also, the use of `LIKE` is overkill if there's not a wildcard (`%`) character in the string. You can switch that to an `=`.

Comment: Yeah, I should have caught that. Edited in.